# Canonical reference for dictionary between $G$-spaces and fiber bundles over $BG$?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

I'm looking for a comprehensive reference (for citation purposes) laying out the basic facts of the equivalence between $G$-spaces and bundles over $BG$ for a discrete group $G$. I'd like it to also include the identifications of the various auxiliary structures: $G$-representations to local systems, group cohomology to cohomology with local coefficients, (Borel) equivariant cohomology and cohomology of the total space of the bundle, the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence and the Serre spectral sequence of the fibration.

This seems like foundational material but I've found this shockingly hard to find in a reference; can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

One reference is the two papers by Nikolaus–Schreiber–Stevenson:

[Principal ∞-bundles – General theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0248v3)

[Principal ∞-bundles – Presentations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0249v1)

In particular, these papers explain the equivalence between G-spaces, spaces over BG, and principal G-bundles.  They also cover twisted cohomology, twisted bundles, gerbes, etc.

Comment: These papers seem like they may be more infinity-y than the original asker may have had in mind. I'd also be interested in a more classical reference where spaces are just spaces.

Comment: @GregFriedman: The second paper makes no use of ∞-categories and is formulated in the traditional language.

Comment: Hmm, I don't mean to be disagreeable, but I just looked at the second paper, and it also seems to be largely about presentations of ∞-toposes using things like simplicial presheaves, simplicial objects in sites, etc. The section labeled "groups" starts off with "Every ∞-topos H comes with a notion of ∞-group object that generalizes the ordinary notion
of group object in a topos as well as that of grouplike A∞ space in Top ≃ Grpd∞. We discuss presentations of ∞-group objects by presheaves of simplicial groups." So, we may have very different interpretations of "traditional"!

Comment: @GregFriedman: Simplicial groups were introduced in 1950s (Kan) and simplicial presheaves in 1980s (Joyal, Jardine), seems reasonably traditional for a topic in homotopy theory.  The OP requested a source for reference purposes, which these papers can certainly provide.